# Find the unique element in an unordered array consisting of duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, big-o

For example, if L = [1,4,2,6,4,3,2,6,3], then we want 1 as the unique element. Here's pseudocode of what I had in mind:

initialize a dictionary to store number of occurrences of each element: ~O(n), 
look through the dictionary to find the element whose value is 1: ~O(n)

This ensures that the total time complexity then stay to be O(n). Does this seem like the right idea?

Also, if the array was sorted, say for example, how would the time complexity change? I'm thinking it would be some variation of binary search which would reduce it to O(log n).

Comment: Since you need to look at every element, you'll never get better than O(n).

Comment: You're right, thank you :D

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes they appear exactly twice (except one)

Comment: If the array has duplicates, do the duplicates appear exactly 2 times, or exactly N times, or any number of times? If the number is always the same, you can binary-search and get O(log n) behavior.

Comment: @Austin: To binary search would require sorting the values first.

Comment: @martineau yes. OP asked if ordering the list would have any effect. If the list is sorted, *and* if the duplicates appear exactly twice, then a binary search is possible (list[2*n] == list[2*n+1] => greater).

Comment: @Austin: Yes, you're right, the OP does mention that possiblity. It would be useful if the OP would clarify how many times a value could be duplicated (and accept an answer accordingly).

Comment: We are not allowing duplicates more than twice. The example I posted above is how each input would like at all times.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

uniques = [k for k, cnt in Counter(L).items() if cnt == 1]
```

Complexity will always be O(n).  You only ever need to traverse the list once (which is what `Counter` is doing).  Sorting doesn't matter, since dictionary assignment is always O(1).

Comment: Can you tell me more about the complexity of the solution that you wrote?

Answer (score 7):

There is a very simple-looking solution that is O(n): XOR elements of your sequence together using the `^` operator. The end value of the variable will be the value of the unique number.

The proof is simple: XOR-ing a number with itself yields zero, so since each number except one contains its own duplicate, the net result of XOR-ing them all would be zero. XOR-ing the unique number with zero yields the number itself.

Comment: ...assuming that all non-unique elements appear an even number of times.

Comment: "Duplicates" means two or more times.

Comment: Duplicates in the context of databases means two or more times. But very clever solution!

Comment: What if the elements of the array aren't simple elements that can be binary XORed with each other?

Comment: @martineau: You could XOR a suitable integer representation of them. For example, if they were strings, you could XOR together `int(binascii.hexlify(s), 16)`.

Comment: Worth noting: this solution uses O(1) space, unlike the `Counter` solution that takes O(n) additional space.

Comment: @nneonneo: Ignoring the duplicates issue — which is currently still unresolved — I believe you're mistaken about it being [O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) and think it would be O(n) like the solution using `Counter`since it requires looking at every element (as @tom10 commented).

Comment: If the same elements are thrice in sequence then will it work? Ex-{1,1,1,2,2,2,3}?

Comment: @martineau: I said O(1) space, not O(1) time.

Comment: @nneonneo: Oops, sorry, I assumed total time complexity because that's what the OP mentioned in their question.

Comment: @Avinash: No, it works reliably only when any identical values are repeated an even number of times (so that  XOR'ring them together results in zero).

Comment: Yeah I know. But in your approach its mandatory that elements must occurs even number of time and that is not he want I think. Your solution could be standard if we want to find the number who occurs odd number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlined algorithm is basically correct, and it's what the `Counter`-based solution by @BrendanAbel does. I encourage you to implement the algorithm yourself without `Counter` as a good exercise.

You can't beat O(n) even if the array is sorted (unless the array is sorted by the number of occurrences!). The unique element could be anywhere in the array, and until you find it, you can't narrow down the search space (unlike binary search, where you can eliminate half of the remaining possibilities with each test).

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, where duplicates can be present any number of times, I don't think you can reduce the complexity below **O(N)**, but for the special case outlined in *dasblinkenlight*'s answer, one can do better.

If the array is already sorted **and** if duplicates are present an **even number** of times as is the case in the simple example shown, you can find the unique element in **O(log N)** time with a binary search.  You will search for the position where `a[2*n] != a[2*n+1]`:

```
size_t find_unique_index(type *array, size_t size) {
    size_t a = 0, b = size / 2;
    while (a < b) {
        size_t m = (a + b) / 2;
        if (array[2 * m] == array[2 * m + 1]) {
            /* the unique element is the the right half */
            a = m + 1;
        } else {
            b = m;
        }
    }
    return array[2 * m];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use variation of binary search if you have array is already sorted. It will reduce your cost to **O(lg N)**. You just have to search left and right appropriate position. Here is the C/C++ implementation of your problem.(I am assuming array is already sorted)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Input: Indices Range [l ... r)
// Invariant: A[l] <= key and A[r] > key
int GetRightPosition(int A[], int l, int r, int key)
{
    int m;

    while( r - l > 1 )
    {
        m = l + (r - l)/2;

        if( A[m] <= key )
            l = m;
        else
            r = m;
    }

    return l;
}

// Input: Indices Range (l ... r]
// Invariant: A[r] >= key and A[l] > key
int GetLeftPosition(int A[], int l, int r, int key)
{
    int m;

    while( r - l > 1 )
    {
        m = l + (r - l)/2;

        if( A[m] >= key )
            r = m;
        else
            l = m;
    }

    return r;
}

int CountOccurances(int A[], int size, int key)
{
    // Observe boundary conditions
    int left = GetLeftPosition(A, 0, size, key);
    int right = GetRightPosition(A, 0, size, key);


    return (A[left] == key && key == A[right])?
        (right - left + 1) : 0;
 }
int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3};
    printf("%d",CountOccurances(arr,7,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the original problem (in either the sorted or unsorted cases). All you're doing is counting the number of occurrences of a particular element. The OP is looking for the single unique element in the list.